# Error in R function rmcorr: Error in psych::r.con(rmcorrvalue, errordf, p = CI.level) : number of subjects must be greater than 3

Tags: r, correlation

I'm trying to do a repeated measures correlation in R using rmcorr, but received the above error, even though I have more than 3 subjects.

```
> scores$SUBJECT
  [1] 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2 
 [36] 2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3 
 [71] 3  3  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5 
[106] 5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6 
[141] 6  6  6  6  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  8  8  8  8  8  8  8 
[176] 8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9 
[211] 9  9  9  9  9  9  10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 11 11 11 11 11
[246] 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12
[281] 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 14 14 14
[316] 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15
[351] 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 17
[386] 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18
[421] 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19
[456] 19 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21
[491] 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21

# Convert data types
scores$SUBJECT<-factor(scores$SUBJECT)
scores$FACTOR1<-factor(scores$FACTOR1)
scores$FACTOR2<-factor(scores$FACTOR2)
```

Interestingly, I was able to perform the correlation on some subsets of the data but not others.

```
# SUBSETS
subset1 <- subset(scores, FACTOR1 == "m1")
subset1a <- subset(subset1, FACTOR2 == "a")
subset1b <- subset(subset1, FACTOR2 == "b")
subset1c <- subset(subset1, FACTOR2 == "c")
subset2 <- subset(scores, FACTOR1 == "mp")
subset2a <- subset(subset2, FACTOR2 == "a")
subset2b <- subset(subset2, FACTOR2 == "b")
subset2c <- subset(subset2, FACTOR2 == "c")

rmcorr(participant = subset1$SUBJECT, measure1 = subset1$SCORE, measure2 = subset2$SCORE, dataset = scores)

rmcorr(participant = subset1a$SUBJECT, measure1 = subset1a$SCORE, measure2 = subset2a$SCORE, dataset = scores)
rmcorr(participant = subset1b$SUBJECT, measure1 = subset1b$SCORE, measure2 = subset2b$SCORE, dataset = scores)
rmcorr(participant = subset1c$SUBJECT, measure1 = subset1c$SCORE, measure2 = subset2c$SCORE, dataset = scores)
```

Specifically

```
rmcorr(participant = subset1$SUBJECT, measure1 = subset1$SCORE, measure2 = subset2$SCORE, dataset = scores)
```

worked, but all of the other calls to rmcorr generated the error. Does anyone know where I went wrong?

Comment: probably rmcorr requires the factor to have more than one level present in the data. What was the error

Comment: The error message is in the title. Also, Factor1 and Factor2 both have more than one level.

Comment: well the error tells you why your code is wrong. when you subset, you only have one subject. yet you should have more than 3 subjects